# Getting Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext error for android deployments in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a a Xamarin Forms solution with iOS and Android projects. They connect to an Azure App Service.

After updating my packages in NuGet I'm getting the following error when running my Android project only, iOS is working fine:

System.InvalidOperationException: A Microsoft Azure Mobile Services assembly for the current platform was not found. Ensure that the current project references both Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile and the following platform-specific assembly: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.

I can't find either references in my assemblies or on NuGet.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

The DLLs were located in:
\packages\Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.3.1.0\lib\monoandroid

Once added there was a conflict:
The type 'CurrentPlatform' exists in both 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, and 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.

Removing Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client solved this issue and the app is working again.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the references to the project manually. So Right Click on the References folder in the Android Project, and search for the missing references.

Comment: There are already references to:
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Analytics
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Analytics.Android.Bindings
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Android.Bindings
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Crashes
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Crashes.Android.Bindings.None of these have the 'MicrosoftAzure' namespace though.

Comment: Check to see if you have WindowsAzure.MobileServices installed. Apparently it interferes with Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/271